# Outlook Web: which UI framework or library is based its new GUI?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, outlook, outlook-web-app

Here is a newbie question: could you recommend me a web UI framework capable to design user interfaces like the new Outlook Web in its last version? I'm asking this because I cannot find a technical paper from Microsoft explainin that.

Note: I'm looking for a technical answer more explained than only say HTML, CSS or JS... in case anyone can recommend a similar framework capable to build that kind of views I would be appreciated. If it is based in Bootstrap or similar framework, please comment that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Office UI Fabric is a framework similar to Bootstrap that contains many of the same components and styles that you see in Outlook Online: http://dev.office.com/fabric/components.

You can see an example of a UI built using a mix of Fabric and Bootstrap with my MessageFiler for Outlook app: http://www.rockinsoftware.rocks/MessageFiler.html

Comment: Nice examples... Thanks Eric... im planning build a Spring MVC application, so I'm looking for frontend support and despites AngularJS is a good candidate, because it's going to pass to 2.0 era, I'm not really convinced about my previous background around it. Office UI Fabric seems to be interesting. Question solved.